# How to parse an url which contains special symbols using URLEncodedUtils.parse?

Tags: java

My code is something like this :

```
String queryString = "";
String url = "http://localhost:8080/xyz.html?param1=paramx&param2=wt_jnknk|nkn|lk_nm&param3=abc";
try {
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8");
for (NameValuePair param : params) {
    if(!param.getName().toLowerCase().equals("param3")){
          queryString = queryString + "&" + param.getName() + "=" + param.getValue();
    }
}
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      return "error";
}
return queryString;
```

This code does not return the queryString and it returns error because the param2 contains "|". How can I handle this?. I can have other special characters in url also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use first the [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to get a valid string.

```
queryString = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

this will result in

> http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fxyz.html%3Fparam1%3Dparamx%26param2%3Dwt_jnknk%7Cnkn%7Clk_nm%26param3%3Dabc

Basically it changes the `|` to `%7`. That you should be able to parse

Comment: I will have to pass url to "URLEncodedUtils.parse". So it should be url=URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");, Right?.